# What's Linux test -a command test for?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, command-line-arguments

Please take a look at the following code,

```
snap=snapshot.file   
touch snapshot.file-1

$ [ -a $snap-1 ] && echo yes 
yes
```

What does the `test -a` command tests for here?

I tried `info coreutils 'test invocation'` and searched for `-a`, but didn't find it in the *file characteristic tests* section, but rather in the *connectives for test* section.

Is such `test -a` command an **undocumented** one?

NB, My system is Ubuntu 13.10 and my `man test` says *GNU coreutils 8.20 October 2012 TEST(1)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure why the `info` page doesn't have it, but running `help test` in `bash` gives the answer:

```
...
    File operators:

  -a FILE        True if file exists.
...
```

So it is simply an "existence" test, no other permissions/attributes checked.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Strange, `man test` doesn't have that either. only `help test` does. Does that mean it is a `bash` *specific* file existence testing?

Comment: @xpt It would seem like that is the case, but for me `/bin/test -a file` worked also...So why it isn't in the manpage I have NO idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running `test` or `[` in `bash`, it's actually probably the built-in version, and not the `coreutils` version in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ type test
test is a shell builtin
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
```

That said, it does appear that the coreutils version implements both `-a` and `-e`, with exactly the same behavior. Maybe `-a` is not reflected in the manpage because it's not [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), so maybe it was added later and that person neglected to update the manpage accordingly. But I can't say I know the history behind why it was added (or even what the `a` is supposed to be short for).

Answer (score 1):

`-a` is the AND operator for combining conditions, so the following shows yes if both directories exist:

> [ -e /root -a -e /usr ] && echo yes

The use of it with a single condition that defaults to an existance test seems like retained old behavior but I can't find it in old man pages.

Reference (scroll down some after `info coreutils 'test invocation'`):

> ### 16.3.6 Connectives for `test'
>
> The usual logical connectives.
>
> `! EXPR'
>        True if EXPR is false.
>
> `EXPR1 -a EXPR2'
>        True if both EXPR1 and EXPR2 are true.
>
> `EXPR1 -o EXPR2'
>        True if either EXPR1 or EXPR2 is true.

Comment: If you look at the coreutils source, the `a` and `e` cases share the same code in the function that handles unary operators, so I don't think it's an accidental thing.